# Why the tutorial of cnn in tensorflow doesn't work?

Tags: tensorflow

I try to test this tutorial https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py  about Convolutional Neural Network, It is explained , but I find this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Convolution_Neural_Network.py", line 161, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "Convolution_Neural_Network.py", line 129, in main
    model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/mnist_convnet_model/")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 171, in __init__
    _verify_model_fn_args(model_fn, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 742, in _verify_model_fn_args
    raise ValueError('model_fn (%s) must include features argument.' % model_fn)
ValueError: model_fn (<function cnn_model_fn at 0x53790c8>) must include features argument.
```

The error is from this line:

```
model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/mnist_convnet_model/")
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me please.

Comment: I don't believe it is the problem, but in the tutorial it seems to be `model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/mnist_convnet_model")` (you don't have /tmp)

Comment: I have already created it and I still having the same error

Answer (score 0):

you probably renamed the variable called 'features' in definition of function cnn_model_fn. I had similiar problem, because I renamed it to 'inputs'.